# Unnest Array of Objects and transform nested values to key/value Pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, transform, unnest

The nested array, **stats**, consists of objects containing key-value pairs.

- Each **key-value pair** is an object with two elements: **the first element** is the **property key** and the **second element** is the **property value**.
- The **goal** is for *statName* and *statValue* to transformed to **key:value** pairs in the outermost array of objects.

I've identified two JavaScript functions on MDN Web Docs that seemed to be somewhat relevant:   **[Object.formEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)** and **[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)**.

- The **Object.fromEntries()** static method transforms a list of key-value pairs into an object.
- The **Object.entries()** static method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable string-keyed property key-value pairs

---

```json
[
  {
    "playerName": "Chris Kirk",
    "country": "United States",
    "countryFlag": "USA",
    "rank": 35,
    "stats": [
      {
        "statName": "Avg",
        "statValue": "70.356",
      },
      {
        "statName": "Total Strokes",
        "statValue": "5,176",
      },
      {
        "statName": "Total Adjustment",
        "statValue": "30.308",
      },
      {
        "statName": "Total Rounds",
        "statValue": "74",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "playerName": "Kevin Yu",
    "country": "Chinese Taipei",
    "countryFlag": "TPE",
    "rank": 36,
    "stats": [
      {
        "statName": "Avg",
        "statValue": "70.386",
      },
      {
        "statName": "Total Strokes",
        "statValue": "3,251",
      },
      {
        "statName": "Total Adjustment",
        "statValue": "57.157",
      },
      {
        "statName": "Total Rounds",
        "statValue": "47",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

What I'm trying to achieve.

```json
[
  {
    "playerName": "Chris Kirk",
    "country": "United States",
    "countryFlag": "USA",
    "rank": 35,
    "Avg": "70.356",
    "Total Strokes": "5,176",
    "Total Adjustment":"30.308",
    "Total Rounds": "74"
  },
  {
    "playerName": "Kevin Yu",
    "country": "Chinese Taipei",
    "countryFlag": "TPE",
    "rank": 36,
    "Avg": "70.386",
    "Total Strokes": "3,251",
    "Total Adjustment": "57.157",
    "Total Rounds": "47"
  }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add a [mcve] to the question

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = [
  {
    "playerName": "Chris Kirk",
    "country": "United States",
    "countryFlag": "USA",
    "rank": 35,
    "stats": [
      {
        "statName": "Avg",
        "statValue": "70.356",
      },
      {
        "statName": "Total Strokes",
        "statValue": "5,176",
      },
      {
        "statName": "Total Adjustment",
        "statValue": "30.308",
      },
      {
        "statName": "Total Rounds",
        "statValue": "74",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "playerName": "Kevin Yu",
    "country": "Chinese Taipei",
    "countryFlag": "TPE",
    "rank": 36,
    "stats": [
      {
        "statName": "Avg",
        "statValue": "70.386",
      },
      {
        "statName": "Total Strokes",
        "statValue": "3,251",
      },
      {
        "statName": "Total Adjustment",
        "statValue": "57.157",
      },
      {
        "statName": "Total Rounds",
        "statValue": "47",
      }
    ]
  }
]

const output = input.map(({stats, ...rest}) => ({
    ...rest, 
    ...stats.reduce((acc, {statName, statValue}) => ({
        ...acc, 
        [statName]: statValue
    }), {})
}))

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map for modify old response and inside map you can loop for states values

```
const formattedResponse = originalResponse.map((item) => {
  // Create a new object to store
  const newObj = {
    playerName: item.playerName,
    country: item.country,
    countryFlag: item.countryFlag,
    rank: item.rank,
  };

  // Iterate through the 'stats' array and add the properties to the new object
  item.stats.forEach((stat) => {
    newObj[stat.statName] = stat.statValue;
  });

  return newObj;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What @evolutionxbox says. But here is a solution for your problem:

```js
const transformedData = data.map((player) => {
  const playerStats = {};
  player.stats.forEach((stat) => {
    playerStats[stat.statName] = stat.statValue;
  });
  delete player["stats"];

  return {
    ...player,
    ...playerStats
  };
});
```

Running:

```js
const data = [{
    "playerName": "Chris Kirk",
    "country": "United States",
    "countryFlag": "USA",
    "rank": 35,
    "stats": [{
        "statName": "Avg",
        "statValue": "70.356",
      },
      {
        "statName": "Total Strokes",
        "statValue": "5,176",
      },
      {
        "statName": "Total Adjustment",
        "statValue": "30.308",
      },
      {
        "statName": "Total Rounds",
        "statValue": "74",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "playerName": "Kevin Yu",
    "country": "Chinese Taipei",
    "countryFlag": "TPE",
    "rank": 36,
    "stats": [{
        "statName": "Avg",
        "statValue": "70.386",
      },
      {
        "statName": "Total Strokes",
        "statValue": "3,251",
      },
      {
        "statName": "Total Adjustment",
        "statValue": "57.157",
      },
      {
        "statName": "Total Rounds",
        "statValue": "47",
      }
    ]
  }
]

const transformedData = data.map((player) => {
  const playerStats = {};
  player.stats.forEach((stat) => {
    playerStats[stat.statName] = stat.statValue;
  });
  delete player["stats"];

  return {
    ...player,
    ...playerStats
  };
});

console.log(transformedData);
```

Comment: note that this will delete `stats` from the objects in the origial array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a valid solution of your problem

```
const unnestData = data.map(d => {
  d.stats.forEach(({statName, statValue}) => d[statName] = statValue)
  delete d.stats
  return d
})
```

Comment: note that this will also modify the original objects in the starting array.